# I can't seem to get foreign keys to work in SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm having an issue that's been blocking me from progressing with an app for a while and I think I'm finally at my wits end of trying to figure it out. For some reason, I can't seem to get foreign keys to work in SQLite.swift/SQLite (I can't figure out whether I'm misusing the library or misunderstanding SQLite in general). I'm trying to use the cascading delete function, and I feel as though I have everything set up correctly, but it isn't working.

Let me make sure my understanding of this is clear first. I have a parent table "Categories" with a child table "Subcategories" that is a parent table to child table "Transactions." Subcategories has a row "category_id" that is related to the "id" row of Categories with a foreign key that cascades on delete. Transactions has a row "subcategory_id" that is related to the "id" row of Subcategories with a foreign key that sets null on delete. When I delete a row from Categories, any row with that category id in Subcategories should also be removed, and any row in Transactions with that subcategory id should have the subcategory id field set to null. Is that correct?

I have all of my SQLite things handled in a single class. Here is a snippet of my code that pertains to the creation of the Subcategories table where I create the foreign keys:

```
do {
    try db!.run(subcategories.create(ifNotExists: true) { table in
        table.column(id, primaryKey: .autoincrement)
        table.column(name, defaultValue: "New Subcategory")
        table.column(sort)
        table.column(category_id)
        table.column(budget_id)
        table.foreignKey(category_id, references: categories, id, update: .cascade, delete: .cascade)
        table.foreignKey(budget_id, references: budgets, id, update: .cascade, delete: .cascade)
    })
} catch {
    print("SQLite: Unable to create 'Subcategories' table")
}
```

[Here is the full code for that class.](https://pastebin.com/jestdupP)

If anyone can shed any light on what I'm doing wrong here, I'll give you my firstborn child (or maybe a thanks at least).

Comment: Are you enabling foreign keys every time you open a database? https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

Comment: @Shawn I haven't, but I can't find anything that mentions that in the documentation for using SQLite.swift? How would I use this expression in swift? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: You just execute the pragma like any other SQL statement that doesn't return a value.

Comment: @Shawn Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer here, and it is in fact related to the keys not being enabled.

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/757